# How to solve this simultaneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$$\dot{x}=yx^4$$
$$\dot{y}=\frac{1}{x^3}-2y^2x^3$$
Where $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dt}$.

I would like to solve for $x$.
I tried to differentiate $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ to see if I can make substitutions, however I was unable to obtain a differential equation of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$y = \dot{x}x^{-4}$$
from the first equation, and so
$$\dot{y} = \ddot{x}x^{-4}-4\dot{x}^2x^{-5}$$
Plugging these into the second equation gives
$$\ddot{x}x^{-4}-4\dot{x}^2x^{-5} = x^{-3}-2\dot{x}^2x^{-5}$$
$$\implies x\ddot{x} - 4\dot{x}^2 = x^2-2\dot{x}^2$$
$$\implies \ddot{x}-2\frac{\dot{x}^2}{x}-x=0$$
Making the substitution $x = 1/u$, the equation becomes
$$\ddot{u}+u = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Replace $y$ with $v=x^3y$, then $\dot x = xv$ and
$$
\dot v = 3x^2y\dot x+x^3\dot y=3v^2+1-2v^2=1+v^2
$$
which you can now solve for $v=\tan(t+C)$ and then for $x=D/\cos(t+C)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT...You can divide the equations and rearrange to get $$y\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2y^2}{x}=\frac{1}{x^7}$$

Substituting $u=y^2$ gives a differential equation which can be solved using the integrating factor method.